# issue about ImageView Matix in android

Tags: android, imageview

I have a question about ImageView transformational matrix,when I try to obtain the Zoom ratio of ImageMatrix ,I get result contain `0` or `negative number`,why?

```
float[] values = new float[9];
mImageView.getImageMatrix().getValues(values);
float scaleX = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
float scaleY = values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];
```

if I set the image in other ways I get the ImageView result right,but **if the image come from camera directly,and the image haven't been rotating** ,when set the imageView and then use Matix to SPIN RECOVERY it ,the zoom ratio result will have 0 and negative number,

every time I get Matrix I use:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix(mPhotoView.getImageMatrix())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got something wrong about using it ,it shouldn't be used like this,`Matrix.MSCALE_X`,`Matrix.MSCALE_Y`,`Matrix.MSKEW_X` and `Matrix.MSKEW_Y`have different use.now I have solve it in another way.